# ssrs-report : how to fix error Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

i have parameters for call table name on my database, for example table name in my db like GPS-RV.1_b.
then i try to call it in my query builder like

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = ' select top 100 X,Y,Z from dbo.' + @tableName
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(100) = N'@tableName nvarchar(100)';
print @cmd
exec sp_executesql @cmd, @ParmDefinition = '@tableName';
```

it's run, but when i try to enter my table name and press ok button, it showing this error

```
------------------------------

An error occurred while executing the query.
Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 214)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1617&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=214&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

is there any missing part from my query?? or i do wrong way??
thanks for help and any advice to fix it.

Comment: that's not how it works. you have concatenated tablename; it's not a parameter

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exec your `@cmd` statement without sent parameters

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = ' select top 100 X,Y,Z from dbo.' + @tableName

print @cmd
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

As @Mitch Whaeat said, `@tableName` is not a parameter, It's just a variable. Remember to assign the value to the `@tableName` variable.

Comment: already test your help, but it showing error like
Incorrect syntax near '-'.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Incorrect syntax near '-'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 102)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1617&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=102&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
"

Comment: in my database, my table have a name with sign combination like minus ' - ' , dot  ' . ' and underline ' _ ' .

Comment: In this case you need to use brackets
`set @cmd = ' select top 100 X,Y,Z from dbo.[' + @tableName + ']'`

Comment: wow, it's absolutely like what i want, thanks a lot @JotaPardo for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need add N to star parameter

```
exec sp_executesql @SCRIPT, N'@R INT out, @C019CodigoMCRE BIGINT , @C138Cedula VARCHAR(13) , @C019JsonDetalle VARCHAR(MAX) ', @R out, @C019CodigoMCRE =  @C019CodigoMCRE_, @C138Cedula = @C138Cedula_, @C019JsonDetalle= @C019JsonDetalle_
```

Answer (score -1):

You declared @cmd as NVARCHAR

```
set @cmd = N' select top';
```

or

```
exec sp_executesql N''+ @cmd +'';
```